Solana Block Height Exceeded On Mainnet
I'm trying to issue simple transactions through my app using USDC on Solana.
I get this error on about 1/3 transactions
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 5TcAUbqXA34oegDTkrm...fzAxZsr14g86CoDZ9tWFjn8 has expired: block height exceeded.

After searching around, the only lead I found was tipping more, which I thought I was doing. Most node providers show the medium sized tip at 20k microlamports and i'm including 100k with it.
This is the code I have for the transfer.
As you can see we have a gasStation which attempts to transfer enough sol to complete the transaction. I assumed the duration of the gas station might be leading to a block height timeout, so once gas is transferred, we recreate the transaction and send it again with a new recentBlockHash
Both attempts seem to have improved the likelihood of it going through, but its still 1/3 that fail
    const accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(toTokenAccount);
    const transaction = new Transaction();

    if (!accountInfo) {
      const associatedTokenAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mintAddress,
        to,
      );
      transaction.add(
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
          from,
          associatedTokenAddress,
          to,
          mintAddress,
          TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        ),
      );
    }

    transaction.add(
      createTransferInstruction(
        fromTokenAccount,
        toTokenAccount,
        from,
        amount,
        [],
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      ),
    );

    const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
    transaction.sign({ publicKey: from, secretKey: signer });

    transaction.add(
      ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
        microLamports: 100_000,
      }),
    );

    if (!skipGas) {
      console.log('> Checking for gas');
      await SolanaService.gasStation(connection, transaction, from);
      // Attempting to recreate the transfer function, since waiting on gas could timout the block for the original transaction
      return SolanaService.transferToken(
        connection,
        fromTokenAccount,
        toTokenAccount,
        from,
        to,
        signer,
        amount,
        mintAddress,
        true,
      );
    }

    console.log('> TRANSFERRING TOKENS');
    return sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
      { publicKey: from, secretKey: signer },
    ])
  }```


Fetching a Fresh Block Hash After Gas Top-Up ( Ensure the block hash is fresh right before sending the transaction.)

Batch the Gas Top-Up with the Main Transaction ( combining the gas station logic into the same transaction, reducing the need to recreate the transaction.)

@IsuruBandara yeah thats what I'm doing with the recursive call
Good idea on batching it! I'll add that for efficiency (though I don't think it solves the problem)

Please modify this line of code:
const transaction = new Transaction();
to

const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
        units: 2000000
      });
      const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
        microLamports: 9000
      });
      const recentBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
      const transaction = new Transaction({
        recentBlockhash: recentBlockhash.blockhash,
      }).add(modifyComputeUnits).add(addPriorityFee);

In case above code sample won't work then please try by increasing these parameter's values
units: 2000000 and microLamports: 9000

Hey, appreciate the answer!
Can you explain what about your code differs from mine and why it would fix the issue?

I am also creating a associated token account of a SPL token  and swapping the tokens on the raydium dex and at at some point I faced a issue of the block height, then after increasing the PriorityFee transaction was successful .
Is above source code resolved your issue ?

Yeah it seems like its just generally a priority fee issue
